# For-looping VBA vectors

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

I'm trying to create a vector in VBA using a for loop. My problem is that VBA doesn't allow me to have a different equation for the first vector coordinate. When trying to run it I get "expected array" as an error message

```
'radius calculations
r(1) = (al * Log(al) / (al - 1)) * rb ' middle radius of block 1, trying to calculate first entry
'in r-vector, since this equation is different from the rest
r_m(1) = rb 'r_i-1/2 i=1

For i = 2 To n_r
    r(i) = al * r(i - 1) ' r_i
    r_m(i) = (r(i) - r(i - 1)) / (Log(r(i) / r(i - 1))) 
Next i
```

al and rb is defined as Double (Public Const), while r is defined as a string. I have only used Matlab in the past, and only read intro guides to VBA (VBA for Dummies etc.)

Greatly appreciate all help in the matter

E

Comment: You write you declared `r` as a string.  But `r(1)` or `r(i)` refer to an array.

Comment: r should be of a numeric data type, e.g. Double, for indexing you need to declare it as an Array, like: Dim r(1 to 5) As Double

Answer (score 2):

VBA doesn't treat strings the same way it treats arrays (like you'd see in other languages).  `r(1)` looks like array syntax to VBA ([as can be seen here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)); therefore, it's going to error out if it's declared as a string.

So, essentially, VBA is interpreting `r(1)` to mean, "I have an array named `r` and I want to store something into element number `1`".  But, instead, it's attempting to do this to an immutable string.

The [Split](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-split-function/) function can be used to turn a string into an array, if that's what you need.

Still, it'll be best if you straight-up [declare an array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264224.aspx) for your vector math.

```
Dim myArray() As Double
Dim myArray2(10, 10, 10) As Double
```

The [ReDim keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) can be used to resize an array, even within a for loop.  (Just don't forget to `ReDim Preserve` if you need to make sure that the contents don't get wiped during this operation).